# Operations on appended DOM elements with jquery

Tags: jquery, dom, append

I've got a form which has one set of fields on load

```
<form id="questionsForm" method="post" action="/author">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    <div class="row questions" id="question-0">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @include('baseviews.panel_question')
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" id="saveQuiz" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</form>
```

After that, I dynamically add extra sets via the `append()` method jQuery, the sets look in the following way and all of them have a class `.questions`:

```
<div class="row questions" id="question-0">
    <div class="col-md-12">
    @include('baseviews.panel_question')
</div>
```

On form submission I want to access all these sets in order to apply particular rules to form fields like this:

```
$('#questionsForm').on('submit', '.questions', function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var valid = false;
    $(this).each(function () {
        var set = $(this).find('.radio');
        set.each(function () {
            if($(this).is(':checked')){
                 valid = true;
                 console.log(valid);
             }
        });
    })
})
```

But this code access only the first set of fields regardless of how many I append afterwards. How can I fix that and select all of them?

Comment: I'm not sure quite how your code is working given that `.questions` is a `div` element which doesn't raise a `submit` event. Does `@include('baseviews.panel_question')` append a form element which then causes a `submit` event to bubble up the DOM?

Comment: You can get rid of the `.each` loop: `var valid = $(this).find(".radio:checked").length > 0;`

Comment: What do you expect `$(this).each()` to do? There's only one element in `this`, so there's nothing to loop over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need event delegation on the .questions div and the submit event only triggers on form elements, do the following:

```
$('#questionsForm').on('submit', function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var valid = false;
    $(this).find('.questions').each(function () {//get all the questions from the form
        var set = $(this).find('.radio');
        set.each(function () {
            if($(this).is(':checked')){
                 valid = true;
                 console.log(valid);
             }
        });
    })
})
```

Comment: the code with your changes is actually works eventually! I will keep in mind that `find()` method for the future cases. Thank you a lot, you just saved me an enormous amount of time!!!